# How to add a JavaScript code in xcode so that i can run it in webview

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

The ads which am integrating is from adbutler. The code for the ad is in javascript. i need to run the js code in UIWebview. Any suggestions.

The sample code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rnd = window.rnd || Math.floor(Math.random()*10e6);
var pid156452 = window.pid156452 || rnd;
var plc156452 = window.plc156452 || 0;
var abkw = window.abkw || '';
var absrc = 'http://ab152067.adbutler-photon.com/adserve/;ID=152067;size=320x100;setID="some number";type=iframe;kw='+abkw+';pid='+pid156452+';place='+(plc156452++)+';rnd='+rnd+'';
document.write('<ifr'+'ame src="'+absrc+'" width="320" height="100" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></ifr'+'ame>');
</script>
```

Comment: How are you loading your webpage in webview? Is that a static html embedded with you app code OR you are loading it using URL?

Comment: its a static html content.

Answer (score 1):

make the code you want to run a function() in the web page.

From iOS WebView call stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: the function

JavaScript function:

```
function adCrapFunction()
{
   alert('Hey there buy something.');
}
```

iOS:

```
[self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"adCrapFunction();"];
```

Some things that will get you:

1. you might have to encode data that you want to pass into the javascript function.
2. you will have to \" if you want javascript strings that you want to pass into the javascript function.
3. You can get data back from stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: but it will be a string, so be careful there. I never had that with my app, but it can happen.

Comment: Thanks John!  We're actually struggling with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not executing the JavaScript.  Are there rumors about it not working in iOS 6?